# Why not work my UITableViewCell Subclass?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make a TableView with a CustomCell, I get the data of a XML web service, I'm parsing whole fine, but when I like show the data in my UITableViewCell subclass only can see the image, the labels not appear, I have the Oulets and instances correctly but just it not work .

[Respository with the code](https://bitbucket.org/Linuxito/uitableviewcell/get/master.zip)

I leave a bitbucket repository to check my code, please help me, I think that is a small error but is hard to solve to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to put break point, that will help you solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your labels begin with a newline character, for example:

> __NSCFString *     @"\n    Casas de empeño ‘exprimen’ a deudores"     0x08cb7c10

You can solve this by trimming white space:

```
cell.cabezaLbl.text = [[dic objectForKey:@"Cabeza"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thanks Great job jejej

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str =  [dic objectForKey:@"Entrada"]
```

`str` is like "\n bla bla bla" so your label should be show multiple lines. You should set `numberOfLines` property of this label 0.

```
cell.entradaLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Or you can do this in interface builder.